# AEM 6.2 - Read AEM DAM XML and append to another XML using XMLStreamWriter stream

Tags: aem

I have XML stream code which is generating the xml like shown below. Code and generated xml is shown below. Now, I want to read another XML file from AEM DAM (content shown below) and append to the xml generated using XMLStreamWriter stream.

XML Stream code is shown below

```
 XMLOutputFactory of = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
 XMLStreamWriter writer of.createXMLStreamWriter(slingResponse.getWriter());
 stream.writeStartDocument("1.0");
 stream.writeStartElement("", “list", “http://www.google.com/schemas/list/1.1");
 stream.writeNamespace("", “http://www.google.com/schemas/list/1.1”);

 writer.writeStartElement(NS, “books”);

 writer.writeStartElement(“http://www.google.com/schemas/list/1.1”, “name”)

 writer.writeCharacters(“test1”);

 writer.writeEndElement();

 writer.writeStartElement(“http://www.google.com/schemas/list/1.1”, “author”)

 writer.writeCharacters(“sample1”);

 writer.writeEndElement();
 writer.writeEndDocument();
```

Above code is generating the xml file like this -

```
     <list xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/list/1.1">
     <books>
       <name>test1</loc>
       <author>sample1</author>
     </books>
     <books>
        <name>test2</loc>
        <author>Sample2</author>
     </books>
     <books>
        <name>test3</loc>
        <author> Sample3</author>
     </books>
    </list>
```

Now, below is the content of XML which is stored in AEM DAM. Here, I want to read this XML file from AEM DAM and append to the xml generated(above) using XMLStreamWriter stream

```
   <list xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/list/1.1">
   <books>
      <name>test4</loc>
      <author>sample4</author>
   </books>
   <books>
      <name>test5</loc>
      <author>Sample5</author>
   </books>
   <books>
      <name>test6</loc>
      <author> Sample6</author>
   </books>
  </list>
```

Currently, I have below code snippet to access the file from AEM DAM. But how to read this xml file and write to XMl stream?

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();                 
    map.put("type", "dam:Asset");
    map.put("path", "/content/dam/sample/en"); 
    map.put ("property", "jcr:content/metadata/dc:format");
    map.put ("property.value", "application/xml");       
    builder= resourceResolver.adaptTo(QueryBuilder.class);
    Query query = builder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map), session);

    SearchResult sr= query.getResult();
```

Finally, i want output like this -

```
     <list xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/list/1.1">
      <books>
       <name>test1</loc>
       <author>sample1</author>
     </books>
     <books>
        <name>test2</loc>
        <author>Sample2</author>
     </books>
     <books>
        <name>test3</loc>
        <author> Sample3</author>
     </books>
     <books>
       <name>test4</loc>
       <author>sample4</author>
      </books>
      <books>
        <name>test5</loc>
        <author>Sample5</author>
      </books>
      <books>
        <name>test6</loc>
        <author> Sample6</author>
      </books>
    </list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a node as an `InputStream` using [`org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils#readFile`](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.8/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html#readFile(javax.jcr.Node))

```
 Node node = ... // your xmlNode
 InputStream in = JcrUtils.readFile(node);
```

From there you can use the input stream to do whatever you like I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. You can get the file as string by using `IOUtils.toString(in)` or You could convert (copy) the `InputStream` to an `OutputStream` and use it with your stream writer like:

```
OutputStream out = ... // this is your output stream
IOUtils.copy(in,out);
XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(out);
```

> The `IOUtils` mentioned here is this one: `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` which ships by default with AEM or you can include a different version in your pom https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I have provided more details in the question. Basically, what i am not understanding is how to append the content of AEM DAM xml to the XML which is generated using the XMLStreamWriter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing xml as `dam:Asset`, the `jcr:content/renditions/original` node (under the asset node) will contain the original binary data, and you should read from that-

adding to your code:

```
Node node = sr.getNodes().next() //first node
InputStream is = node.get("jcr:content/renditions/original/jcr:content").getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary().getStream();
//now you can work with this stream (is) and its content

// if you want to simply write to slingresponse
slingResponse.getWriter().write(IOUtils.toString(is, UTF8));

// if you want to work with xml elements you will have to parse the xml first
```

Comment: thanks awd for this approach. Can you please guide me how can i copy input stream content to an XMLStreamWriter?

Comment: are you trying to write the xml to slingRespnse?

Comment: yes awd, i have to write the xml to slingRespnse. Basically, I need to know the way to copy input stream content to an XMLStreamWriter.

Comment: I updated answer with code for writing to response, I think the code in the other answer should work for creating XMLStreamWriter.

Comment: sorry, but still I am not clear as my requirement is to append the input steam content (node elements) to the existing XMLStreamWriter stream before the  writer.writeEndDocument() line (last line in the description of the questions). Because XMLStreamWriter stream already has few node elements, i just need to append after that. My apology if i was not clear in beginning.

Comment: you will have to parse the xml and write element by element.

Comment: Can you pls let me know if there is any simpler API to read the Input stream node elements and append them after the existing XMLStreamWriter stream elements.